# White Space at the bottom of app when it goes back to parent view from current

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller, uitoolbar

I am working on an app which has `UITabBar` at the bottom of app. One of the tab holds `UITableviewController` and another holds `UIViewController`. `UITableViewController` is customized to hold grid of images. When I tap on these images, my App pushes another view in `navigationcontroller` but at this time I remove tabbar and put toolbar. So far everything works fine. But when I go back to parent view I see white space at the bottom of it. I am hiding toolbar in `viewWilldisapper` so that I can not see on parent view.
    Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong?
Regards,
Sumit.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to hide toolBar in viewWillDisappear. When you use the method hidesBottomBarWhenPushed to hide tabbar it will automatically hides and display when you push and pop. Try removing the piece of code where you are hiding toolBar in viewWillDisappear.

Comment: If I remove that then I get empty toolbar right over the top of tabbar in parent view. I have done everything programming not through IB.